# How to open a list of address in browser

Tags: python, browser, hyperlink

I have a list of links, which is stored in a file. I would like to open all the links in my browsers via some script instead of manually copy-pasting every items.

For example, OS: MAC OS X; Browser: Chrome; Script: Python (prefered)

Comment: Maybe Javascript can do this??

Comment: If you want a JS answer, ask for a JS answer. Don't play the douche-y "maybe SOME OTHER LANGUAGE can help me" game to force a response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module.

```
import webbrowser

urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.reddit.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com']
b = webbrowser.get('firefox')
for url in urls:
    b.open(url)
```

P.S.: support for Chrome has been included in the version [3.3](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/webbrowser.html), but Python 3.3 is still a release candidate.

Comment: or you could use `webbrowser.open(url)` and it will use the "default" browser (similar to the `open` command).

Comment: +1 this is cleaner (and therefore, I think, better) than my answer for every case unless it doesn't support the browser you want to use.

Comment: if `google-chrome` is not the default browser you still can use it before Python 3.3: `webbrowser.get("google-chrome %s")`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on a mac, you can just use the subprocess module to call `open http://link1 http://link2 http://link3`. For example:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["open","http://www.google.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"])
```

Note that this will just open your default browser; however, you could simply replace the `open` command with the specific browser's command to choose your browser.

Here's a full example for files of the general format

```
alink
http://anotherlink
```

(etc.)

```
from subprocess import call
import re
import sys

links = []

filename = 'test'

try:
    with open(filename) as linkListFile:
        for line in linkListFile:
            link = line.strip()
            if link != '':
                if re.match('http://.+|https://.+|ftp://.+|file://.+',link.lower()):
                    links.append(link)
                else:
                    links.append('http://' + link)
except IOError:
    print 'Failed to open the file "%s".\nExiting.'
    sys.exit()

print links
call(["open"]+links)
```

Comment: note: `webbrowser` already uses `open location` command by default on a Mac